# Converting xml from UTF-16 to UTF-8 using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, utf-8, utf-16

What's the easiest way to convert XML from UTF16 to a UTF8 encoded file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may not be the most optimal, but it works.  Simply load the xml and push it back out to a file. the xml heading is lost though, so this has to be re-added.

```
$files = get-ChildItem "*.xml"
foreach ( $file in $files )
{
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
    $doc.set_PreserveWhiteSpace( $true );
    $doc.Load( $file );

    $root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
    $xml = $root.get_outerXml();
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + $xml

    $newFile = $file.Name + ".new"
    Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $newFile $xml;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you explicitly set the encoding to save somewhere?

Comment: If I knew how, I would. It appears to be the default though.

Comment: @Exotic Hadron: no, unless it's valid XML too.

Answer (score 16):

Well, I guess the easiest way is to just not care about whether the file is XML or not and simply convert:

```
Get-Content file.foo -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 newfile.foo
```

This will only work for XML when there is no

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

line.

Comment: If you want to do it without creating a new file, you can wrap the get-content in parenthesis: (Get-Content File.foo) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 File.foo

Comment: How do you do this for files in a directory and subdirectories?

Comment: `gci -rec -fi * | %{(gc $_ -enc unicode) | set-content -enc utf8 $_.fullname}`. Fairly straightforward, actually.

Comment: @Joey, a small correction on your powershell script...  
`gci -rec -fi * | %{(gc $_.fullname -enc unicode) | set-content -enc utf8 $_.fullname}`

Comment: No need of using `FullName` there. `Get-Content` knows how to deal with a `FileInfo`.

Comment: @Joey, unfortunately for me it was complaining that it could not find the path. I think it must be converting the FileInfo object to a string.
`Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\WorkingFolder\FileName.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:26
+ gci -rec -fi *.txt | %{(gc <<<<  $_ -enc ascii) | set-content -enc utf8 $_.fullname}
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WorkingFolder\FileName.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

FileName.txt was in a subfolder of C:\WorkingFolder.

Comment: does this get you: `UTF8 with BOM`? see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596982/1747983

Answer (score 9):

Try this solution that uses a `XmlWriter`:

```
$encoding="UTF-8" # most encoding should work
$files = get-ChildItem "*.xml"
foreach ( $file in $files )
{
    [xml] $xmlDoc = get-content $file
    $xmlDoc.xml = $($xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",$encoding,"")).Value
    $xmlDoc.save($file.FullName)      
}
```

You may want to look at `XMLDocument` for more explanation on `CreateXmlDeclaration`.

Comment: Thank you very much for caring to provide such a brief, an technically better, answer to such an old question!

Comment: I had to get it done and I found this solution even before seeing this question. I felt it was normal to offer it. With little effort someone can even use it to copy while converting the encoding of the files. Regards.