# Is it possible to use something like reposurgeon to turn all commits of a UTF-16 file to UTF-8 in a git repo?

Tags: git, utf-16

I have a git repository that has a UTF-16 file in it. Its only UTF-16 by accident, the file could be encoded in 7-bit ascii without a loss of data. I'd like to use something like [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) to convert the file to UTF-8 so that git diff will work  with older revisions of the file and I don't have to resort to git difftool. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just covert the file to UTF-8 and commit it, e.g. with:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 input-file.txt > input-file.txt.fixed
# Check here that the conversion worked OK
mv -i input-file.txt.fixed input-file.txt
git commit -m 'Convert input-file.txt from UTF-16 to UTF-8' input-file.txt
```

---

*Update after a clarifying comment:*

If you want to rewrite that file at every commit in the history of `HEAD`, you can use `git filter-branch`, something like:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
    'iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 input-file.txt > input-file.txt.fixed  &&
     mv input-file.txt.fixed input-file.txt' HEAD
```

Of course, if you're rewriting history in this way, it may cause problems if you have shared this repository with anyone.  (I haven't tested that command - use it with care, probably only a new clone of your repository.)

Comment: Because I want the history in UTF-8 not just the HEAD.

Comment: Mark, the short story is that work. The long story is if you want to do it from Windows, you need to launch it from git bash, not from PowerShell. I started mucking about with how do it it with powershell, including using [the Powershell alternative to iconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750449/converting-xml-from-utf-16-to-utf-8-using-powershell) here, but then I realized I could launch git bash.